# Parsing timestamps from string and rounding seconds in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I have a spark DataFrame with a column `"requestTime"`, which is a string representation of a timestamp. How can I convert it to get this format: `YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, knowing that I have the following value: `20171107014824952` (which means : `2017-11-07 01:48:25`)?

The part devoted to the seconds is formed of 5 digits, in the example above the seconds part is = `24952` and what was displayed in the log file is 25 so I have to round up `24.952` before applying the `to_timestamp` function, that's why I asked for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format).

Comment: No it's not the same question, here I have a very different time format. thanks anyway @pault

Comment: If you read the answer on the linked duplicate you will see that the format can be specified.

Comment: If you have checked the format of my column, you will realize that the part devoted to the seconds is formed of 5 digits, in the example above the seconds part is = 24952 and what was displayed in the log file is 25 so I have to round up 24.952 before applying the "to_timestamp" function, that's why I asked for help

Comment: In the future, it's helpful to add the details of what you've tried and why it's not working in the question. I have edited those into the question for you. Please read [ask] and [how to create good reproducible spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following spark DataFrame:

```python
df.show()
#+-----------------+
#|      requestTime|
#+-----------------+
#|20171107014824952|
#+-----------------+
```

With the schema:

```python
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- requestTime: string (nullable = true)
```

You can use the techniques described in [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format) to convert this to a timestamp. Since the solution is dependent on your spark version, I've created the following helper function:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

def timestamp_from_string(date_str, fmt):
    try:
        """For spark version 2.2 and above, to_timestamp is available"""
        return f.to_timestamp(date_str, fmt)
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):
        """For spark version 2.1 and below, you'll have to do it this way"""
        return f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(date_str, fmt))
```

Now call it on your data using the appropriate format:

```python
df.withColumn(
    "requestTime", 
    timestamp_from_string(f.col("requestTime"), "yyyyMMddhhmmssSSS")
).show()
#+-------------------+
#|        requestTime|
#+-------------------+
#|2017-11-07 01:48:24|
#+-------------------+
```

Unfortunately, this [truncates the timestamp instead of rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007740/does-unix-timestamp-truncate-or-round-milliseconds).

Therefore, you need to do the rounding yourself *before* converting. The tricky part is that the number is stored as a string - you'll have to convert it to a `double`, divide by `1000.`, convert it back to a `long` (to chop off the decimal and you can't use `int` as the number is too big), and finally back to a string.

```python
df.withColumn(
    "requestTime",
    timestamp_from_string(
        f.round(f.col("requestTime").cast("double")/1000.0).cast('long').cast('string'),
        "yyyyMMddhhmmss"
    )
).show()
#+-------------------+
#|        requestTime|
#+-------------------+
#|2017-11-07 01:48:25|
#+-------------------+
```